# Declare a requirement to be installed from github branch

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

What is the correct way to have a specific branch of a repo as a dependency, and be able to use it for running tests too?

If you only specify `dependency_links`, setuptools would install it as a dependency but does not install it to run the test:

```
setup(
    packages=['utils', 'tokens'],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://github.com/Demonware/jose/tarball/python3#egg=jose-1.1.0'
    ],
    # install_requires=['jose'],
    use_2to3=True,
    test_suite='test_jwt',
    zip_safe=True,
)
```

I rely on `python3` branch of `jose` library. When I run `setup.py test`, it complains that it cannot find `jose` package.

If I add `install_requires`, it simply does install the master branch and not the `python3` branch that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dependency_links=[
    'https://github.com/Demonware/jose@python3#egg=jose-1.1.0'
],
install_requires=['jose'],
```

Let me explain. The `pip/setuptools` VCS URLs have the following structure:

```
git+https://repoURL@reference#egg=project-version
```

RepoURL is a VCS repository URL (`https://github.com/Demonware/jose` in your case).

Reference is a tag, a branch or a commit ID (SHA1, could be shortened to 7-10 characters); in your case it's branch `python3`.

Project name and version in the `#egg=` hash are necessary for `setuptools` to recognize an URL as the URL for project named in `install_requires` — `setuptools` must know the name before downloading the project so the `#egg=` hash is the only way to convey that information. Version is not strictly necessary but it would be useful for such a case as `install_requires=['jose>=1.1.0']`.

Comment: I added an explanation for `pip` VCS URL structure.